# How to change the angular-material datepicker current date color

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I want to change the color of the current date in angular-material if that day is disabled since I have made a function that disables 2 days from now.

Example if today is 8-24-16 the datepicker disables 8-24-16 (today) and 8-25-16 (tomorrow),  so I want to change the color that displays the current date if the date is disabled. Because when the current date disabled it shows the current date 8-24-16 (today) in a very light blue that is hard to see so I want to change that color to a different color that highlights more.

I tried looking at the css of angular-material but I couldn't find anything related to the css color of a disabled current date or a normal not disabled current date. I don't mind changing the color of both the normal current date and the disable current date. Also, my function that disabled the days sets the date from to days from now I don't know if this affects something.

Here is my code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Delivery Date:</label>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"
        md-max-date="maxDate"
        md-min-date="minDate"
        md-date-filter="disabledWeekends"
        ng-disabled="disabled">
    </md-datepicker>
</div>
```

My Controller

```
//adding two days
   $scope.maxDate = new Date(
        $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
        $scope.myDate.getMonth(),
        $scope.myDate.getDate() + 2);

    $scope.minDate = new Date(
        $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
        $scope.myDate.getMonth(),
        $scope.myDate.getDate() + 2);


    $scope.myDate = $scope.minDate;


 $scope.disabledWeekends = function (date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
            return day === 1 || day === 2 || day === 3
                    || day === 4 || day === 5;
        };
```

Comment: Hey bill it'll be really tough to figure it out like can you give us fiddle link or anything else? You can share any already available link as well.

Comment: that's the thing I don't know too much about CSS so I don't know where to start I looked at the angular-material css but I couldn't find anything like current-date-color or anything like that , I could create a css class but how can I know the name of that specific  element.

Comment: That is why we need to look at the working code to determine the element which is causing the problem. Open the code in the chrome browser and press `ctrl+shift+i` then select the element you want to change and check which css class is affecting it.

Answer (score -1):

You can add new class for disable date's html tags eg: class="disableDates" and define color for this class in your css file.